# Connecting MSSQL Database Using PHP PDO Objects

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to connect MSSQL Database Server Using PHP PDO Object Like This:

```
$dsn='mssql:host=***.***.***.***;dbname=***';      
$username='***';
$passwd='***';

try{

$baglanti=new PDO($dsn,$username,$passwd);
$baglanti->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
$baglanti->exec("SET NAMES UTF8");
ini_set('max_execution_time', 2000000);

}catch(PDOException $e){ 

    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I am getting this error after this coding:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 10007 'NAMES' is not a recognized SET option. [10007] (severity 5)
```

How can I perform this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSSQL does not support `SET NAMES UTF8`

Try using:

```
$pdo = new PDO('dblib:host=localhost;dbname=databasename;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password');
```

Or

```
$pdo = new PDO( 
    'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=defaultDbName', 
    'username', 
    'password', 
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8") 
);
```